# Merge rows based on two unique id, and combining information in excel

Tags: excel, merge, excel-formula, duplicates

I've got a set of columns like this in excel:

```
                                       Size Volume
Post    Origin  Destination     Size20  Size40  Size60
WN      HONG KONG   Denmark      13      132      7
DH      DALIAN      Spain        39      136     19
DN      HONG KONG   Denmark      13      132      7
DH      DALIAN      Spain        0       146     23
WN      HONG KONG   Denmark      11      19      5
DH      HONG KONG   Denmark      21      5       17
```

and I'm having trouble merging the rows based on by their Origin and    Destination ID (by using excel formula), to something like this>

```
                                        Size Volume
Post    Origin  Destination     Size20  Size40  Size60
WN      HONG KONG   Denmark      24      151      12
DH      DALIAN      Spain        39      282      42
DN      HONG KONG   Denmark      34      137      24
```

Comment: I think you want to "aggragate" not merging, please specify which are the fields you want to use (looks like Post, Origin, Destination) and the aggregate formula (it looks to be Sum)

Comment: I tried consolidate tools but I cannot spacify 2 ID (origin and Destination). Am I missing something here? and yes, you are correct Post, Origin, Destination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for `Query Editor`. You could start the query going to the `Data` menu, then press `From Table` and follow as in the pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: OMG. Thanks Macro. I wasn't aware of this tool.

Comment: @ann I have changed your question to tag it under `Aggregate`. Merging is when you have two tables and want to get one

Comment: I see. Thanks @Marco

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a sumifs, which sums certain ranges depending on certain conditions. You might want to try the following formula:

```
=sumifs(D:D,$A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)
```

Where the first part `D:D` is the range which contains the actual cells to sum. The second part `$A:$A` is the first criteria range and `$A1` the criteria for this range. The last four parts are two other criteria ranges and criteria for these ranges.

Therefore I expect the Post to be in column A, the Origin to be in column B, the Destination in column C and you want to sum up Size 20 which I expect to be in column D.

Comment: Thanks. I want to sum up Size 20 , 40 and 60 actually. column D, E and F. I tried your method for all D1:F80 but got value error

Comment: With sumifs you can only sum up one range at a time. Therefore you can use the above formula to sum up size 20 and edit the formula to sum up size 40 and 60. Does the above formula work for you to sum up only size 20?

Comment: Then you can change the first part in the formula to either E:E or F:F to sum up sizes 40 and 60.